# Code from online cookie popup tutorial not setting cookie

Tags: cookies, warnings, popupwindow, setcookie

I am trying to set up a cookie policy pop-up on site.
I followed an online tutorial to the letter (I thought) but it doesn't work.
The banner shows up as expected, but on clicking accept, the page seems to refresh but no cookie is set and the banner is still there.

I have looked through the tutorial and all seems to be as he typed. Maybe someone could suggest what could be wrong.
The styles were placed in the css file, but I think the issue must be with the php. I have looked for alternative codes but they are so different I am not sure they would work with this method.

I wonder whether it has something to do with the isset commands.

Also, is there a way to ensure that when the cookie is set and is acknowledged that you stay on the same page rather than going to the root directory?

This is on the top of the html code i.e. before doctype

```
if (isset($_GET['accept-cookies'])) {
setcookie('accept-cookies', 'true', time() + 31557600);
header('Location: ./');
}
?>
```

This is the section with the banner (I like the way it looks so prefer not to change the style codes)

```
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['accept-cookies'])) {
    ?>

    <div class="cookie-banner">
    <div class="cookie-container">
    <p style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 500; font-size: medium;">We use cookies to track usage and preferences. By using this website we will assume that you consent to their use as per our <a href="/privacy.html"><u>Privacy and Cookie Policy</u></a>.</p> 
        <p style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 600; font-size: medium;"><a href="?accept-cookies" class="cookiebutton">Okay</a></p>    
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Just in case you need it, here are the css parts

```
    background-color: #abd1ff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #4a6894;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4a6894;

}

.cookie-banner {
    background: #6c9bd3;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 98%;
}

.cookie-banner .cookie-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #1f2b3a;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

I was going to add a slide down function, but when I added for it not to display initially in the css code, the banner disappeared even when the js file was referred to with the slide down code.

Any help on what I could add to make it work, what is missing, would be great.

THANK YOU!!!!

No error messages have been seen. Banner just won't disappear and cookie is not set.